# Is more than one instance of tag in a SIP user valid?

Tags: uri, sip, rfc

I'm writing some code to parse SIP users (From:/To: headers) and I ran into a case that threw an exception in my code:

```
From: "1000"<sip:1000@192.99.32.105>;tag=313030300131333539323834383930;tag=4e6f6e650132363237343735343432
```

There are two instances of tag. I can't understand clearly from the RFC if it is valid to have multiple tag parameters in the uri. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not allowed. [RFC3261 section 7.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-7.3.1) states:

> Even though an arbitrary number of parameter pairs may be attached to
> a header field value, any given parameter-name MUST NOT appear more
> than once.